# Replacing A String With a HTML Tag Using PHP

Tags: php, html

Im reading in a piece of HTML text. I want to remove all HTML tags except paragraphs and headings. To do this i use str_replace to replace the tags that i want with string placeholders. Then strip the HTML tags. Then finally replace the string placeholders with the original HTML code. This is where it is failing.

```
$Text = 'ManyENH3 different';

$updatedText = str_replace("ENH3", "</h3>", $Text);
```

The above code wont remove the ENH3 string. I have tried messing around and it doesnt work when there is no space before or after the word. I tried using preg_replace and it returns a blank string.

Comment: Why you dont use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php) ?

Comment: or http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php  in english even :)

Comment: The variable name was just a typo when i added the code. Its a lot more complicated than this in my actual script i just simplified the issue

Comment: Although you should use @BenjaminPoignant's answer, what is the problem with your code? It works fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/MHLzIM

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

```
$updatedText = strip_tags($Text, '<p><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6>');
```

Comment: aw damn i wish i had of known this when i started this script. Unfortunately the data is now in a database. I can rewrite the script and start again from scratch processing the data, but ive already come so far i would like if i could fix the stored data

Comment: $Text = 'ManyENH3 different';
    $stored_data_tag = array("ENH1","ENH2","ENH3","ENH4","ENH5","ENH6","ENP");
    $real_tag = array("</h1>","</h2>","</h3>","</h4>","</h5>","</h6>","</p>");
    $updatedText = str_replace($stored_data_tag, $real_tag, $Text);
    var_dump($updatedText);

Comment: Awesome That fixed it! thank you. Double thank you for the strip_tags information. this will be really useful for me in the future